# Ansible - Kerberos. Can´t find client principal

Tags: kerberos, ansible

I have a problem with ansible and Kerberos.

If I start a playbook I get the follwing message:

> fatal: [sgtest002]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg":
>   "kerberos: authGSSClientInit() failed: (('Unspecified GSS failure. 
>   Minor code may provide more information', 851968), (\"Can't find
>   client principal admin@TESTDOMAIN.CLOUD in cache collection\",
>   -1765328243))", "unreachable": true}

But I have still a valide Credential (klist):

> Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000 Default principal:
>   admin@TESTDOMAIN.CLOUD Valid starting       Expires
>   Service principal 02/28/2019 11:29:35  02/28/2019 21:29:35 
>   krbtgt/TESTDOMAIN.CLOUD@TESTDOMAIN.CLOUD
>           renew until 03/07/2019 11:29:

Have anyone an idea or can help me please?

Another issue is:
If I will create a second Cred with the command `kinit ....@TESTDOMAIN.CLOUD` the other credential will be deleted (or isn't visible anymore with the command `klist`).

Best Regards
Steffen

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?